# How to pass elasticsearch json output to .net

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

Sorry if this is a repeat question or if im not clear with my question.

Currently i'm storing the json output from elasticsearch in a .json file and using it through stream reader for further processing.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("D:/abc.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
}
```

Instead of doing that, is there any way I can directly take the ES output and use it and further process it to my requirement.

Can someone help me with this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could also send HTTP-requests via the [RESTful API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) and get json back directly. But a library that supports the native API (as suggested by Petr) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Elasticsearch.Net & NEST](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net)?

Seems it has a .NET api for querying ElasticSearch.